# Most arguments to my controller ctor, only being used as pass through to base controller, in Unity+MVC pattern, Any better ways?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyController(Obj1 obj1, Obj2 obj2, Obj3 obj3, Obj4 obj4, Obj5 obj5, Obj6 obj6)
    {
         // use all params
    }
}

public class MyController : MyBaseController
{
     public MyController(Obj1 obj1 .. Obj9 obj9) : base(obj1 .. obj6)
     {
         // use only two or three params, reset passed to base ctor
     }
}
```

So the above is my situation, where my base controller needs most arguments, but I don't myself, and I feel it's cluterring my ctor, BUT! at the same time I don't want to use property injection, because my properties are made public, and I hate making things public  if I don't need to.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you explain question with more details.., its litle confusing.

Comment: Are you unit testing your controllers? If not you could call the service locator directly in your base controller. `ServiceLocator.Resolve<IService>()` Also, having lots of parameters smells of too many concerns being handled in one controller. Is there any way you can break this apart?

Comment: I am unit testing my controllers, so that is not an option. The fact is that these params are needed for a given request to our service, and therefore it's right to handle them here, but grr...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using property injection instead. See 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650198.aspx for more information.

Comment: Property injection is not so awesome because my properties have to be public.

Comment: Property injection has its place but as a couple of other posters mentioned we need to know what the questioner is trying to achieve. Based off the question I would say that @Ryan's comment on the question is the closest to an answer.